# Determine the constant $a$ So that $\lim_{x\to 0}$ $f(x)$ exists.

Tags: calculus

**Question:**

Determine the constant $a$ So that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ exists when:

$$f(x) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \arctan{\frac{1}{x}} &\quad\text{if $x$ > 0}\\
       \frac{e^{ax} - 1}{x} &\quad\text{if $x$ < 0}\\
     \end{cases}$$

**Attempt at a solution:**

We see that the $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \arctan{\frac{1}{x}} \rightarrow \frac{\pi}{2}$

The limit $\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{e^{ax}-1}{x}$ can be derived by the following reasoning:

If we set $y = e^{ax} - 1$ and $x = \frac{\ln{1+y}}{a}$ we see that when $x \rightarrow 0$, that $y \rightarrow 0$

This gives us:

$\lim_{y\to 0} \frac{a y}{\ln(1+y)}$

I am stuck here. Have I used a good approach for this problem?

I am not supposed to use L'Hospitals rule.

Comment: Yes that is right @ClaudeLeibovici

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use Maclaurin series expansion. 
Write $ln (1+y) = y - \frac{1}{2}y^2 + \frac{1}{3}y^3 - \frac{1}{4}y^4 + ....$

Then cancel out the $y$'s so the limit $\dfrac{ay}{ln(1+y)}$ becomes $a$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use L'Hopital's rule. Specifically,

$$\lim_{y\to0}\frac{ay}{\ln(1 + y)} = \lim_{y\to0}\frac{a}{(\frac{1}{1 + y})}$$

Which was found by taking the derivative of the numerator and denominator. Note that this equality only holds because $\lim_{y\to0}ay = 0$ and $\lim_{y\to0}\ln(a + y)=-\infty$.

Then, simplified by the continuity of polynomials:

$$\lim_{y\to0}a(1 + y) = a$$

Thus, we have that $a = \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am looking for a solution that would not involve L'Hospitals rule.

Comment: To avoid l'Hopitâl put $1+y=e^{u}$ and use the series expansion of $e^{u}
$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use taylor expansion for $e^{ax}$.

$e^{ax} = 1 + (ax) + \frac{(ax)^2}{2!} + \frac{(ax)^3}{3!}+... + \frac{(ax)^n}{n!}+...$

$e^{ax} -1 = (ax) + \frac{(ax)^2}{2!} + \frac{(ax)^3}{3!}+... + \frac{(ax)^n}{n!}+...$

$\frac{e^{ax} -1}{x} = (a) + \frac{a^2x}{2!} + \frac{a^3x^2}{3!}+... + \frac{a^nx^{n-1}}{n!}+...$

So as $lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{e^{ax} -1}{x} = a$

Thus, $a = \frac{pi}{2}$